# Image change problem using keypressed() method

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to make a doodle jump game and currently I cant find a way to make the still image change to leg image once it lands on the ground and then change back to still. It kind of does that for one side but not not for both. I've tried using nested if, but then it wouldn't detect the button press. Here's the code:

```java
GameObject game;

PImage doodle;

void setup() {
  size(640, 800);
  smooth(4);
  frameRate(10);

  doodle = loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/ytwebph.png");
  game = new Doodle(new PVector(width/2, height-doodle.height*2), doodle);

  game.setWidthAndHeight(new PVector(width, height));
}
void draw() {

  background(200);
  game.display();
  game.move();
}

void keyPressed() {
  game.setMove(keyCode, true);
}

void keyReleased() {
  game.setMove(keyCode, false);
}

protected class Doodle extends GameObject {

  protected float velocityY, gravity, time;
  protected float groundPosition;
  protected int facing = 0; //0 = right; 1 = left

  protected Doodle(PVector position, PImage picture) {
    super(position, picture);
    gravity = 20;
    time = 0.4;
    velocityY = 35*gravity*time;
    super.setSpeed(10);

    groundPosition = position.y - picture.height;
  }

  public void move() {
    if (isRight || position.y < groundPosition) {
      this.picture = doodleImg[0];
      facing = 0;
    } else if (isLeft || position.y < groundPosition) {
      this.picture = doodleImg[2];
      facing = 1;
    }

    position.x = position.x + speed*(int(isRight) - int(isLeft));

    //border control
    if (position.x+picture.width/2 <= 0) {
      position.x = this.getWidthAndHeight().x-picture.width/2;
    } else if (position.x+picture.width/2 >= this.getWidthAndHeight().x) {
      position.x = 0-picture.width/2;
    }

    //jump
    velocityY -=  gravity * time;
    position.y -=  velocityY * time;
    if (position.y >  groundPosition) {
      if (facing == 0) {
        this.picture = doodleImg[1];
      } else if (facing == 1) {
        this.picture = doodleImg[3];
      }
      position.y =  groundPosition;
      velocityY = 35;
    }
  }
}

public class GameObject {
  public PVector position, widthAndHeight;
  public int size, speed;
  public PImage picture;
  public boolean  isLeft, isRight;

  public PImage[] doodleImg = new PImage[6];

  public GameObject(PVector position, PImage picture) {
    this.position = position;
    this.picture = picture;
    widthAndHeight = new PVector(0, 0);
    speed = 1;

    //0,1 right; 2,3 left; 4,5 shoot;
    doodleImg[0] = loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/ytwebph.png");
    doodleImg[1] = loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/Y0cFSFK.png");
    doodleImg[2] = loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/FL3IhU5.png");
    doodleImg[3] = loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/YuqWihj.png");
  }

  public void move() {
    position.x = 0;
  }

  public void display() {
    image(picture, position.x, position.y);
  }

  public boolean setMove(int keycode, boolean isPressed) {
    switch(keycode) {
    case LEFT:
      return isLeft = isPressed;

    case RIGHT:
      return isRight = isPressed;

    default:
      return isPressed;
    }
  }


  protected PVector getWidthAndHeight() {
    return widthAndHeight;
  }

  void setSpeed(int speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
  }


  public void setWidthAndHeight(PVector newWidthAndHeight) {
    widthAndHeight = newWidthAndHeight;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the `facing` state, dependent on the `isRight` and `isLeft`:

```java
if (isRight) {
    facing = 0;
} else if (isLeft) {
    facing = 1;
}
```

The set the image dependent on the state of `facing` and the vertical position `position.y`:

```
if (position.y < groundPosition) {
    this.picture = doodleImg[facing==0 ? 0 : 2];
} else {
    this.picture = doodleImg[facing==0 ? 1 : 3];
}
```

---

[image]

```java
public void move() {

    if (isRight) {
        facing = 0;
    } else if (isLeft) {
        facing = 1;
    }

    if (position.y < groundPosition) {
        this.picture = doodleImg[facing==0 ? 0 : 2];
    } else {
        this.picture = doodleImg[facing==0 ? 1 : 3];
    }

    position.x = position.x + speed*(int(isRight) - int(isLeft));

    //border control
    if (position.x+picture.width/2 <= 0) {
        position.x = this.getWidthAndHeight().x-picture.width/2;
    } else if (position.x+picture.width/2 >= this.getWidthAndHeight().x) {
        position.x = 0-picture.width/2;
    }

    //jump
    velocityY -=  gravity * time;
    position.y -=  velocityY * time;
    if (position.y >  groundPosition) {
        position.y =  groundPosition;
        velocityY = 35;
    }
}
```